# Independentsoft Exchange Web Services HTML from message is null

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

Using the code examples provided by Independentsoft:

```
PropertyName myPropertyName = new PropertyName("Disabled", StandardPropertySet.PublicStrings, MapiPropertyType.String);
Exists restrictionExists = new Exists(myPropertyName);

response = service.FindItem(StandardFolder.Inbox, MessagePropertyPath.AllPropertyPaths, new Not(restrictionExists));
```

we are getting the message but the BodyHtmlText is null...

Using Exchange Server 2010 SP2.

Anyone had any problems with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FindItems doesn't return the body (and a number of other properties) you need to make a GetItem Request on the Item in question to get these properties see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508824.aspx